# T-SQL Optimized conditional join

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, query-optimization

Hey guys it's Brian from OMDbAPI.com

I hit a little speed bump when trying to use a single query for both Movie and Episode data. I recently started collecting additional Episode details in a separate table (being only two new columns have been added, Season #/Episode #) I put them in a separate table because those columns would be null in my main table 90% of the time but the other columns do work across movies/episodes (title/rating/release date/plot etc.)

So I'm trying to use a single query for returning Movie data but if the ID has a type = 'episode' return the additional fields from the other table. Problem is I don't know that ID is an episode until it's queried, and the least amount of calls to the database (smaller execution plan) the better, as this is called hundreds of times per second (currently 25+ million requests a day)

I created a small [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2253/7) of what I'm trying to achieve.

My question is what is the best method with the least performance cost to show these fields if it's an episode and completely suppress them if not? Is Dynamic SQL my only option? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a ton of value to leaving off the null fields, and handling it in code. That is to say, why not just join the tables every time, and then check (in code) if/when the episode fields are null?

Comment: I think I will have to do a mix of what @aronchick and John recommended. I think I'm going to move the Season/Episode fields back into the main table and have the code which posts the response to the client handle stripping them out if they are null/not an episode ID.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07dff/1 seems to be better but I still have a join to get the series title from the same table.

Comment: Especially if you join EVERY TIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that each Movie row is associated with at most one Episode row, you are certain to get the best query plans by putting the episode data in the Movie table instead of in a separate one.  That avoids having to determine during query execution whether to look at the episode data, and it also avoids any need for a JOIN when you do need it.

Having the 90% NULL episode data in your Movie table will cost you some space, and therefore it will have *some* performance impact, but I'm inclined to think that the resulting simpler query plans will offset that cost.

JOINing the tables every time is your next best bet, I think.  That gives you reasonably simple query plans, and looks for performance gains through reducing the size of the Movie data.  Still, as a general rule, the fewer JOINs you perform, the faster your queries will run.

Comment: Honestly there is more episodes (1.2 million) than movies (700k) in the table, so this may be a good option to keep it all under one giant table to avoid the joins.

Comment: The problem is that won't you duplicate the movie data if a single movie has multiple episodes?

Comment: @aronchick Every movie, series, episode has it's own unique ID/row. i.e. Game of Thrones series ID is "944947" and Season 1 Episode 1 ID is "1480055" but I also have to make reference to the series ID (root ID) within each episode so I can return the seriesTitle which is shown in the new SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Agreed. My point is that if you flatten to a single table, then you'll have a Movie column ("Game of Thrones") for every Episode ("Winter is Coming", "The Kings Road", etc).